# Lightning Page Dynamic Action "No operators available"

Tags: lightning, landing-page, dynamic-actions

I am trying to set a filter for a quick action on a Lightning Page for the Case object. The criterion I am trying to set is "if `Record > Parent Case > Case Id` is not null".

However when I select the Id field I get "no operators available" for my filter. Not sure why that field is selectable if there's no filter that can be built around it.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried just parent case Id not equal to null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seem to be WAD, When defining filter criteria on 'Set Component Visibility' within lightning app builder it wont allow you to set a field type of lookup(Case Id).
[image]

Kindly review limitation [here](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdoMgUAJ/lightning-component-set-component-visibility-to-reference-lookup-field-types) and vote for this feature and check list of [Supported Objects, Fields, Field Types, and Operators](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.lightning_page_components_visibility.htm&type=5).

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing to solve my issue is go to the parent object and select a field that I know would exist. In my case I knew the parent Case record would have the record type populated so I used that instead of the id to verify a parent exists.